# Hiding layer dynamically from layers groups in GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript

I have created a layer group (using 15 layers) in GeoServer. I can access this layer group through OpenLayers & it's working fine. As per the client requirement, I need to develop a layer switcher (for ON & OFF layer) for certain layers.

How can I hide certain layers from this layer group?

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn the layers in a layer group on and off independently. If your client needs to turn layers off then you need to request them separately in OpenLayers.